# Not compilation when labelling x-axis ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels, ggpattern

I have a dataset with two facors (`f1` and `f2`) and two responses (`r1` and `r2`). For the `f1`, I although in the dataset it is coded with A, B, C, etc, I want to use specific names. However, when I tray to add a  `scale_x_discrete()` RStudio is not capable of compiling the code.

Here is a MWE that actually works:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(tidyverse)
library(car)
library(multcomp)
library(palmerpenguins)
library(ggpattern)
library(multcompView)
library(egg)


dput(example)
structure(list(f1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 
9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L), levels = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", 
"F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K"), class = "factor"), f2 = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("1", 
"2"), class = "factor"), r1 = c(10, 11, 12, 14, 11, 13, 18, 19.5, 
20, 19, 23, 25, 5, 7, 9, 12, 21, 24, 9, 8, 15, 13.5, 8, 9, 10, 
12, 9, 11, 16, 17.5, 18, 17, 21, 23, 3, 5, 7, 10, 19, 22, 7, 
6, 13, 11.5), r2 = c(7, 8, 9, 11, 8, 10, 19.5, 21, 21.5, 20.5, 
18, 20, 0, 2, 4, 7, 16, 19, 4, 3, 10, 8.5, 8, 9, 10, 12, 9, 11, 
20.5, 22, 22.5, 21.5, 19, 21, 1, 3, 5, 8, 17, 20, 5, 4, 11, 9.5
)), row.names = c(NA, -44L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

example

example$f1 <- as.factor(example$f1)
example$f2 <- as.factor(example$f2)


example_r1_anova<- aov(r1 ~ f1*f2, data = example)
summary(example_r1_anova)
example_r1_summary<-group_by(example, f1, f2) %>%
  summarise(mean=mean(r1), sd=sd(r1))%>%
  arrange(desc(mean))
print(example_r1_summary)
tukey_example_r1 <- TukeyHSD(example_r1_anova)
tukey_example_r1
example_r1_tukey.cld <- multcompLetters4(example_r1_anova, tukey_example_r1)
example_r1_tukey.cld
example_r1_cld <- as.data.frame.list(example_r1_tukey.cld$`f1:f2`)
example_r1_cld
example_r1_summary$Tukey <- example_r1_cld$Letters
print(example_r1_summary)

example_r1_summary$r <- rep(c("r1"),each=22)


example_r1_summary


example_r2_anova<- aov(r2 ~ f1*f2, data = example)
summary(example_r2_anova)
example_r2_summary<-group_by(example, f1, f2) %>%
  summarise(mean=mean(r2), sd=sd(r2))%>%
  arrange(desc(mean))
print(example_r2_summary)
tukey_example_r2 <- TukeyHSD(example_r2_anova)
tukey_example_r2
example_r2_tukey.cld <- multcompLetters4(example_r2_anova, tukey_example_r2)
example_r2_tukey.cld
example_r2_cld <- as.data.frame.list(example_r2_tukey.cld$`f1:f2`)
example_r2_cld
example_r2_summary$Tukey <- example_r2_cld$Letters
print(example_r2_summary)

example_r2_summary$r <- rep(c("r2"),each=22)


example_r2_summary


example_r <- rbind(example_r1_summary, example_r2_summary)


example_r$r <- as.factor(example_r$r)


ggplot(example_r, aes(x = f1, y = mean, fill = r, pattern = f2)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color="black",position = "dodge", alpha = 1, width=0.7)  +
  geom_col_pattern(alpha=0.5, color="grey20",width=0.7, position="dodge", pattern_fill="black", pattern_density=0.1, pattern_angle=45, pattern_spacing=0.015, pattern_key_scale_factor=0.6)+
  scale_pattern_manual(name="f2", values = c("1" = "none", "2" = "circle"),labels = c("f21", "f22"))  +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-sd, ymax=mean+sd), color="black", position = position_dodge(0.7), width = 0.25, show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text(aes(label=Tukey, y=mean+sd), vjust=-0.5, position = position_dodge(0.7), size = 6.5,  colour = "gray25") +
  scale_fill_manual(name="r",values = c("#E7B800", "#CC79A7"), guide = guide_legend(label.hjust = 0, override.aes = list(pattern = "none")))+
  theme_bw(base_size = 20) +
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(), panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),axis.text=element_text(size=20), axis.title=element_text(size=22,face="bold"), legend.title=element_text(size=20, face="bold"),legend.text=element_text(size=20), axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),legend.position = c(0.5, 0.9),legend.box = "horizontal")+ 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),limits=c(0, 35))
```

The result is the following figure:

[image]

However, when I add the discrete scale in the x-axis, I get nothing but a `Error in seq.default(from, to, by) : invalid '(to - from)/by'`

```
ggplot(example_r, aes(x = f1, y = mean, fill = r, pattern = f2)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color="black",position = "dodge", alpha = 1, width=0.7)  +
  geom_col_pattern(alpha=0.5, color="grey20",width=0.7, position="dodge", pattern_fill="black", pattern_density=0.1, pattern_angle=45, pattern_spacing=0.015, pattern_key_scale_factor=0.6)+
  scale_pattern_manual(name="f2", values = c("1" = "none", "2" = "circle"),labels = c("f21", "f22"))  +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-sd, ymax=mean+sd), color="black", position = position_dodge(0.7), width = 0.25, show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text(aes(label=Tukey, y=mean+sd), vjust=-0.5, position = position_dodge(0.7), size = 6.5,  colour = "gray25") +
  scale_fill_manual(name="r",values = c("#E7B800", "#CC79A7"), guide = guide_legend(label.hjust = 0, override.aes = list(pattern = "none")))+
  theme_bw(base_size = 20) +
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(), panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),axis.text=element_text(size=20), axis.title=element_text(size=22,face="bold"), legend.title=element_text(size=20, face="bold"),legend.text=element_text(size=20), axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),legend.position = c(0.5, 0.9),legend.box = "horizontal")+
  scale_x_discrete(name="", labels = c(
    `A`= expression(ChCl:Lactic~acid),  
    `B` = expression(ChCl:2~Lactic~acid),
    `C` = expression(ChCl:3~Lactic~acid), 
    `D` = expression(ChCl:Oxalic~acid),
    `E` = expression(ChCl:"1,4"-butanediol:Water),  
    `F` = expression(ChCl:2~Levulinic~acid),
    `G` = expression(ChCl:2~Urea),
    `H` =  expression(ChCl:2~Glycerol),
    `I` = expression(Betaine:2~Levulinic~acid), 
    `J` = expression(Betaine:2~Urea:Water),
    `K` = expression(Betaine:2~Lactic~acid)))+ 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),limits=c(0, 35))
```

I guess the problem is in the `expression()` of the x-axis labels, but I don´t know any other way to do it.

Comment: Hm. The issue is somehow related to using `geom_col_pattern` and a rotated axis text, i.e. your code works fine when dropping one of both.

Comment: And is there any possibility to keep them both?

Comment: If I knew an option I would have added it as an answer. To me this looks like a bug, but perhaps someone else can offer a solution.

Comment: To make sure it is not related to you version, have you tried another version of R?

Comment: Yes, I used the previous R version, and then the most updated one avilable.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error unfortunately

Comment: Somewhat surprisingly, I ran your last code chunk in a fresh R session with updated packages and it now works for me.  I was getting the same error as you before.

Answer (score 0):

Following from stefan's identification of the underlying issue, you can keep `geom_col_pattern` and rotated axis text by initially setting the angle to 0, and then manually changing it to 45 in the gtable.

```
p1 <- ggplot(example_r, aes(x = f1, y = mean, fill = r, pattern = f2)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color="black",position = "dodge", alpha = 1, width=0.7)  +
  geom_col_pattern(alpha=0.5, color="grey20",width=0.7, position="dodge", pattern_fill="black", pattern_density=0.1, pattern_angle=45, pattern_spacing=0.015, pattern_key_scale_factor=0.6)+
  scale_pattern_manual(name="f2", values = c("1" = "none", "2" = "circle"),labels = c("f21", "f22"))  +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-sd, ymax=mean+sd), color="black", position = position_dodge(0.7), width = 0.25, show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text(aes(label=Tukey, y=mean+sd), vjust=-0.5, position = position_dodge(0.7), size = 6.5,  colour = "gray25") +
  scale_fill_manual(name="r",values = c("#E7B800", "#CC79A7"), guide = guide_legend(label.hjust = 0, override.aes = list(pattern = "none")))+
  theme_bw(base_size = 20) +
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
        axis.text=element_text(size=20), 
        axis.title=element_text(size=22,face="bold"), 
        legend.title=element_text(size=20, face="bold"),
        legend.text=element_text(size=20), 
        axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 1),
        legend.position = c(0.5, 0.9),
        legend.box = "horizontal") +
  scale_x_discrete(name="", 
                 labels = c(
    `A`= expression(ChCl:Lactic~acid),  
    `B` = expression(ChCl:2~Lactic~acid),
    `C` = expression(ChCl:3~Lactic~acid), 
    `D` = expression(ChCl:Oxalic~acid),
    `E` = expression(ChCl:"1,4"-butanediol:Water),  
    `F` = expression(ChCl:2~Levulinic~acid),
    `G` = expression(ChCl:2~Urea),
    `H` =  expression(ChCl:2~Glycerol),
    `I` = expression(Betaine:2~Levulinic~acid), 
    `J` = expression(Betaine:2~Urea:Water),
    `K` = expression(Betaine:2~Lactic~acid)))+ 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),limits=c(0, 35))

p2 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p1))
p2$grobs[[7]]$children[[2]]$grobs[[2]]$children[[1]]$rot <- 45
grid::grid.newpage()
grid::grid.draw(p2)
```

Comment: I obtained the plot in the plot zoom of RStudio, but when I save it using ```ggsave("example.png", width=20, height=12, units="in",dpi = 120)``` the resulting plot does not show the rotated x-axis labels.

Comment: Moreover, I had problems compiling the code, and after a couple of times I run ```grid::grid.draw(p2)``` RStudio suddenly terminated the session.

Comment: Edited to use `scale_x_discrete`.

Comment: I managed to obtained the png file using ```ggsave("example.png", p2, width=40, height=12, units="in",dpi = 120)``` but the thing is that the x-axis labels are "cut" in half, no matter the x-axis limits or the width of it.